# How to identify customer with stripe webhook in Python/Flask

Tags: python, flask, stripe-payments, webhooks

I've created few plans and saved Stripe subscription.id and customer id into my database. Now I am creating webhook to receive JSON data to update expiry and if and few other fields. All I need now to figure out that how to filter user according to whom webhook is about so I can update model accordingly. Following is my view for webhook in Flask.

```
@app.route('/webhooks', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def webhook():
    event_json = json.loads(request.data)
    event = stripe.Event.retrieve(event_json['id'])
    if event.type == 'invoice.payment_succeeded':
    # Not sure how to query specific user what event is about
    invoice = event.data.object
    elif event.type == 'customer.subscription.updated':
    #or
    elif event.type == 'customer.subscription.active_until':

    subscription = event.data.object
```

I've created 6 plans and all are working fine such as I can delete from local server and it gets deleted automatically from stripe as well. I create a plan and it gets updated to stripe as well. All I need is to update "date" for updated package with webhook data. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stripe.com/docs/api#subscriptions

https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_object

you can find the customer_id and subscription_id from the data received in webhook event. you can print the data `print(event_json['data'])`